# How do I refactor a code well using Action?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question regarding Action and refactoring. Following code is essentially what I am doing. I figured since there are repeated codes, I will try and create a method that holds the common activity and use Action for cleaner codes sake. (In the `SomeSettingChangeIHaveToDoCommonlyBeforeFAR`) However, because those common codes are very small even in real code, I feel like the code is not that cleaner.

```
public void FindAndReplace1(bool isThisGood)
{
    ... some find and replace code ...
}

public void FindAndReplace2(int somePara)
{
    ... other find and replace code ...
}

public void SomeSettingChangeIHaveToDoCommonlyBeforeFindAndReplace(Action findAndReplace)
{
    ... change setting ...
    findAndReplace();
    ... change setting back ...
}

public void Main()
{
    if (conditionA)
        SomeSettingChangeIHaveToDoCommonlyBeforeFindAndReplace(FindAndReplace1(true));
    else
        SomeSettingChangeIHaveToDoCommonlyBeforeFindAndReplace(FindAndReplace2(1));
}
```

While it does shorten the code a bit, because the common code is not that long, the readability of code I feel dropped a bit. Also does not help that I have a long as sentence as my method name.

Is it still a good practice to use action for such a case?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write it.

```
private void FindAndReplace(bool condition)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        FindAndReplace1(true);
    }
    else
    {
        FindAndReplace2(1);
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    ChangeSetting();
    FindAndReplace(conditionA);
    ChangeSettingBack();        
}
```